# Creating a data frame from poorly stored list data (Removing the first row which is junk)

Tags: r, list

Our professor keeps giving us assignments to work with in R but instead of giving us easier data we normally have to pull from the web.

This block of code does that:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/slipopinion/18"
page <- read_html(url)
table <- html_table(page, fill = FALSE, trim = TRUE)
```

However this also gets included in the table data:

> table [[1]]
>                                                                                                                                                                          X1 1 SEARCH TIPS\r\n                                            Search
>   term too short \r\n                                            Invalid
>   text in search term. Try again
>                               X2 1 ADVANCED SEARCHDOCKET SEARCH

So I am having a hard time understanding how to format this data into a data frame because doing something like `as.data.frame(table)` gives me this error,

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE,
>   check.names = TRUE,  :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 1,
>   11, 8, 7, 2

Comment: Your professor is doing you a favour, real world data is messy :) Assuming that you want the table for each month, it may be better to get the tables using `html_nodes("table")` with a selector for the desired tables, before using `html_table`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can approach it two ways. If you are sure that only the first type of error occurs, you can search for the `Search term too short` by `grepl`, and exclude any element in the list `table` before performing `bind_rows`.

```
library(dplyr)
table[unlist(lapply(
  table, 
  function(x) sum(grepl("Search term too short", x))
)) < 1] %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Otherwise, because the other 'nice' elements of the list have the same column names/format, you could also use that.

```
table[unlist(lapply(
  table, 
  function(x) sum(grepl("Docket", names(x))) > 0
))] %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick I understand the unlist and bindrows but the function(x) sum ... stuff doesn't make sense to me but I guess that it filters the data to select from table?

Comment: @BaileyMiller The `sum` exists because `grepl` is run on multiple elements. You can try decomposing it one by one to see what these are doing!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector to distinguish the tables with the data from other tables on the page, such as the search box. In this case, the data tables are of class `table-bordered`:

```
page %>% 
  html_nodes("table.table-bordered") %>% 
  html_table()
```